# How to create decorator calling function 20 times only?

Tags: python, decorator

I need to create decorator for function. It should 20x return result of function, and after that 20 times should only return none and "out of memory" string.

I wrote something like that, but it call function 40 times. Im new in decorators, can someone help me?

My code:

```
   def oom(func):
    count = 0
    def oomHelper(*args):
        if count < 20:
            func(*args)
        else:
            print('Out Of memory')
            return(None)
    return oomHelper
    count = count + 1


@oom
def addTwo(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return(print(c))

addTwo(1,4)
addTwo(1,4)
addTwo(1,4)
.
.
addTwo(1,4)
addTwo(1,4)
addTwo(1,4)
addTwo(1,4)
x25
```

And I except to have 20 results, and 5 out of memory. But I got:

```
result1
restult2
.
.
.
result20
out of memory
result21
result22
...
```

Comment: You can't put a print after a return

Comment: It works fine with me

Comment: How do you call "addTwo" (edit the question to show it as properly formatted code)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher added :) In my case now it print 19x result, and 20th is out ouf memory, and then again 19 result and one out of memory. My excpetation is: 20x result, and all after out of memory

Comment: @martin, 19 result ... did you start counting at 0? because if you did, then there are the 20

Comment: (1) The shown code will never print "out of memory". (2) You must move setting of variable "count" to zero out of "oomHelper". Either to "oom" or as global variable. Otherwise it will be reset on each call of "addTwo".

Comment: I just edit to do some explanations

Comment: As azro already hinted and as I said, the shown code can't produce the shown output. Just copy and paste the real code into the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher ok, so I change while to if, I move count out , and i change a print() with return. And still can't repair that code. Now I got 20x result, and nothing else. I don't know how to print that comunicate and None in same time

Comment: In "oomHelper" the variable "count" must be declared as "nonlocal" yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code (seems you've updated it to something else while I was typing my answer) will print 20 statements right after the first call to the function. You need to replace `while` with `if` and actually `return` the result instead of just calling the function inside `oomHlper` after updating the `count`. You'll also need to add `nonlocal count` inside `oomHelper` for it to be able to update the `count` (alternatively declare count as a list with one element and increment that element). E.g. like this:

```
 def oom(func):
    count = 0
    def oomHelper(*args):
        nonlocal count
        if count < 20:
            count = count + 1
            return func(*args)
        else:
            print('Out Of memory')
            return None
    return oomHelper
```

Comment: So I was close, but not close enough. Thank u very much Alexander!